# Usefulness of using class_implements VS instanceof

Tags: php, optimization, doctrine-orm

In Doctrine's source code if stumbled upon the following test:

```
if (in_array('Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection', class_implements($var))) {
    // ...
}
```

I don't get why not using `instanceof` instead:

```
if ($var instanceof Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection) {
    // ...
}
```

which is better in many ways.

Is there a tangible reason for doing this?

Maybe performances? But really, is there any real difference here, it seems to me it would be like [simple VS double quotes](http://nikic.github.io/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class_implements` will return an array of all the interfaces that are implemented by a specified class.

One reason to use `class_implements` over `instanceof` is that you can use `class_implements` **on a string** that is the name of a class:

```
<?php
interface HasTest {
    public function test();
}

class TestClass implements HasTest {
    public function test() {
        return 'This is a quick test';
    }
}

$test = array (
    'test' => 'TestClass'
);


// !! Using instanceof
var_dump($test['test'] instanceof HasTest);

// !! Using class_implements
var_dump(in_array('HasTest', class_implements($test['test'])));

/**
 * Output:
 *
 * bool(false)
 * bool(true)
 */


$class = new $test['test'];
var_dump($class instanceof HasTest);

/**
 * Output:
 * bool(true)
 */
```

Comment: I'm afraid your code is very wrong. See: http://3v4l.org/QTm9L Using the class name with `new` in front of it (i.e. just `HasTest`) makes PHP use it as a constant. Since it doesn't exist, PHP turns it into the `"HasTest"` string.

Comment: You are extremely correct about me being very wrong, and I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ahhh now I see your point (the small mistake distracted me from the main point), thank you for taking the time to update!

Answer (score 6):

By definition, `class_implements` refers specifically to `interfaces` where `instanceof` refers to the class itself and all of its parents. In the example you provided, the code is verifying the implementation of an interface, and using `instanceof` could cause unwanted results.

From the [PHP Manual instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php)

> instanceof is used to determine whether a PHP variable is an
>   instantiated object of a certain class:
>
> instanceof can also be used to determine whether a variable is an
>   instantiated object of a class that inherits from a parent class:
>
> Lastly, instanceof can also be used to determine whether a variable is
>   an instantiated object of a class that implements an interface:

From the [PHP Manual class_implements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php)

> class_implements — Return the interfaces which are implemented by the
>   given class

Comment: Yes, though in that situation that's very weird because `Collection` is an interface of the Doctrine project, so there is no reason it could be a class...

Answer (score 1):

They both seem to be doing the same thing. But they really aren't. One reason to use class_implements could be to check if a class implements a certain interface. When using instanceof you have no idea if the class is an interface or just a class.

Answer (score 0):

instanceof will return false if your parent class implements an interface. However class_implements will return the implemented interface of your parent.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more? I don't understand your answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the opposite is the case: `instanceOf` returns true for parent classes as well.